# Four to One Game Server

Tags: python, javascript, html, game, server

The two player game *four-to-one* works by leaving four stones on a table. Each player may remove 2 or 1 stones from the table. The first player who *cannot* take away any stones loses. I created a web page that allows you to play this game against a computer that plays the game perfectly<sup>1</sup>.

Here is the code:

## server.py

```python
import hug
import json
from hug.middleware import CORSMiddleware

# Probably should never do this but lol.
api = hug.API(__name__)
api.http.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware(api))

def do_move(pos, mov):
    """
    Given a particular position perform a move in four to one.
    Note: Assumes validity of move.
    """
    return pos - mov


def gen_moves(pos):
    """
    Generate every possible move given a position in the game four to one.
    """
    if pos == 1:
        return [1]
    elif pos == 0:
        return []
    else:
        return [1, 2]

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Collection of functions to update state of the best position found.
# old is the previous best state data, new is the challenger.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

def loss_loss(old, new):
    return new

def loss_win(old, new):
    return old[0], max(old[1], new[1])

def win_loss(old, new):
    return old[0], min(old[1], new[1])

def no_op(old, new):
    return old

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

STATES = {
    "LOSS" : { "LOSS" : loss_loss, "WIN" : loss_win },
    "WIN"  : { "LOSS" : win_loss,  "WIN" : no_op },
}

@hug.get('/')
def next_best_move(pos: hug.types.number):
    """
    Given a position, returns the next best move that someone should play
    Arguments:
    pos -- The current position of the board.
    """
    moves = gen_moves(pos)
    with open('fto1.json') as raw_data:
        data = json.loads(raw_data.read())
        best = moves[0]
        best_stats = [data[str(do_move(pos, moves[0]))]['value'],
                      data[str(do_move(pos, moves[0]))]['remoteness']]
        for move in moves:
            move_stats = (data[str(do_move(pos, move))]['value'],
                          data[str(do_move(pos, move))]['remoteness'])
            old_best_stats = best_stats
            best_stats = STATES[best_stats[0]][move_stats[0]](best_stats, move_stats)
            if best_stats != old_best_stats:
                best = move
    return best
```

## logic.js

```js
/**
 * A representation of the game four to one that 
 */
var game = new StateMachine({
    init: 'playerTurn',
    transitions: [
        { name: 'playerMove', from: 'playerTurn', to: 'computerTurn' },
        { name: 'computerMove', from: 'computerTurn', to: 'playerTurn' },
    ],

    data: {
        board: 4,
    },

    methods: {
        onPlayerMove: function(lifecycle, amount) {
            this.board -= amount;
            if (this.board <= 0) {
                $("#board span").text("Game over");
            } else {
                $("#board span").text(this.board);
            }
        },
        onComputerMove: function() {
            self = this;
            return $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {pos: self.board },
            }).done(function (resp) {
                self.board -= resp;
                if (self.board <= 0) {
                    $("#board span").text("Game over");
                } else {
                    $("#board span").text(self.board);
                }
            });
        },
    },
});

$('document').ready(function() {
    /**
     * Remove one "stone" from the board.
     */
    $("#remove1").on('click', function() {
        game.playerMove(1);
    });

    /**
     * Remove two "stones" from the board.
     */
    $("#remove2").click(function() {
        game.playerMove(2);
    });

    /**
     * Check for updates in the state, used to determine if the computer can m-
     * ake a move.
     */
    window.setInterval(function() {
        game.computerMove();
    }, 2000);
});
```

## index.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script
      src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="state-machine.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="logic.js"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="board">
      <span>4</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button id="remove1">-1</button>
      <button id="remove2">-2</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

There is a [github project](https://github.com/thyrgle/fto1/tree/cdde4959ef4b2e83c478aab630b15902d4e0a1f8) here so feel free to view/clone/download that if you find that easier to work with.

I haven't worried about styling the game yet, so it looks kind of aesthetically displeasing.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Well, you start off in a winning position, so you can pretty much always beat the computer.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you might be mostly interested in feedback on the Python code, I am still working on my Python skills. I can say that the use of storing the data in the JSON file and reading it looks good. Perhaps I can offer more feedback on the Python code in the future.

I can however offer feedback on the JavaScript.

#### Code duplication

It appears that the code in the `onPlayerMove()` and `onComputerMove()` has some redundancy. The redundant code could be abstracted into a separate method like below:

```
updateBoardByAmount: function(amount) {
    this.board -= amount;
    if (this.board <= 0) {
        $("#board span").text("Game over");
    } else {
        $("#board span").text(this.board);
    }
}
```

Then that method can be called when necessary:

```
onPlayerMove: function(lifecycle, amount) {
    this.updateBoardByAmount(amount);
},
onComputerMove: function() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {pos: this.board },
    }).done(this.updateboardByAmount.bind(this));
}
```

Notice [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) was used to bind the callback of the AJAX call to the method (though ensure [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility) doesn't become an issue) - this means the variable `self` is no longer needed and thus removed.

#### DOM lookups

While it may be negligible for a simple page like this, for pages with more complex DOM structures it would be beneficial to cache DOM lookups. For example, we can add a variable before the state machine is instantiated:

```
var messageContainer;
```

Then in the jQuery DOM loaded callback, set that to the DOM element accordingly:

```
$('document').ready(function() { //DOM ready callback
    messageContainer = $("#board span");
```

And then use that variable when necessary - for example:

```
messageContainer.text("Game over");
```

#### jQuery DOM-loaded callback

This is nothing to worry about, but the format of the jQuery DOM-loaded callback (i.e. `$('document).ready(function() {`) *works but is deprecated*<sup>[1](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)</sup>.

The recommended format is simply:

```
$(function() {
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://api.jquery.com/ready/</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually was looking for help with both. I am more familiar with Python the language, but less familiar with `hug` than I am with jQuery. I am going to hold off on accepting for a little bit to see if there are any other suggestions. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure - I feel like one should wait (perhaps 1+ days) so as to allow other users that might potentially provide an answer to do so